# How can I securely handle shipping rate options in my web app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I request shipping rates from an external API and get results like:

```
ground  : '$1'
express : '$5'
```

Then I show these options to user, where they pick one. Ideally they would submit an ID representing which option they picked, and I would look up the corresponding option, but for me to look it up, I need to have a stored list of options. I can store the list of options in my database, but I will need to update it if they go back and change their address, or the items in their cart.

This means I'm essentially caching and re-caching shipping options which seems like a lot of overhead for what feels like a relatively simple task.

Is there a more straightforward way to do this that I am overlooking?

Comment: Why not store the list of options in `$_SESSION`? Either way it doesn't sound like that much overhead to me.

Comment: @Jordan: `$_SESSION`? I think you're thinking of PHP. This is Ruby. You would use `session` if that was the case.

Comment: Haha, thanks Ryan. Definitely spaced out on this one.

Comment: Either way, I'm using rails but it is a more general design question :) This is the road I'm going down, although I'm storing it in an `orders` table but that is referenced in the session.

Answer (score 0):

Why store it? Dynamically generate the form/drop-down based on the response from the API, and set the value of the drop-downs to contain, not an ID, but the dollar rate. Then the param you get back in your controller is the dollar amount from the API, and inserted into the form, not  a record ID.

Assuming the shipping rates change from time to time, there's no point in storing it anyway. Generally, that's the purpose of the API, so you can always just look it up when needed. On the other hand, it's unlikely that the shipping rate for a given order is going to change within the space of a user's session.

To reflect your comments below, you could cache the shipping rate, total order weight, and the destination address at the time of the order. Then, only re-request a new shipping rate if either weight, items in the order, or destination address change.

Comment: The problem is preventing someone from manipulating the form and sending a shipping cost of $0, or -$100. I need to compare it against something, right?

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry I missed that - of course you're right. You could populate the drop-down with the shipping *type* value instead of price (i.e. 1 = standard shipping, 2 = express shipping, etc.) and then you calculate the price the final price on checkout. Store the types of shipping you support in your DB. You can insert the price into the drop-down via an API call, and then just make a 2nd API call during final calculation I suppose. You could cache it to try to save on API calls, but you will need to set a cache expiration time to help keep shipping costs as accurate as possible.

Comment: Store the final, quoted shipping costs in the order itself, so it won't differ between what you told the customer when they placed the order, and when the money actually comes out of your account. If you're concerned about shipping costs going up (and you losing money) between the order and the actual ship, then add a small margin (1-2%) to the shipping cost on every order to cover such issues, or just eat the cost.

Comment: This is essentially the solution I have gone with. This way what the customer sees and what they pay is sure to be the same, and they can't tamper with the data. I cache the quoted shipping rates along with the weight of the order and the ship-to address. If weight or address change, the rates are re-requested, otherwise the cache is used. If you'd like to update your answer I'll checkmark it, unless someone else has a brilliant idea :)